# How to find complexity for the following program?

Tags: python, big-o, code-complexity

So I am not a CS major and have hard time answering questions about a program's big(O) complexity.

I wrote the following routine to output the pairs of numbers in an array which sum to 0:

```
asd=[-3,-2,-3,2,3,2,4,5,8,-8,9,10,-4]

def sum_zero(asd):
    for i in range(len(asd)):
        for j in range(i,len(asd)):
            if asd[i]+asd[j]==0:
                print asd[i],asd[j]
```

Now if someone asks the complexity of this method I know since the first loop goes thorough all the `n` items it will be more than (unless I am wrong) but can someone explain how to find the correct complexity?

If there is better more efficient way of solving this?

Comment: The outer loop goes through `n` items every time, where n is `len(asd)`. For each of these `n` times, the inner loop triggers some number of times that's ≤ n... if both loops ran `n` times, it'd be n^2. Try drawing out a square of n^2 items... that's a first step.

Comment: Your program is clearly O(n^2) where n is the length of the asd array. You make n(n-1)/2 iterations on the loop, so that's why your program has that complexity. The operations inside the loop require constant time, but are done O(n^2) times.

Comment: I assume that the program intends to find all the pair which add up to 0? Your program is O(n^2) (any decent textbook (like CLRS)) will show you how to derive it from the algorithm -- usually by example of selection sort or something like that), if you sort the list and then use binary search to find the matches then the complexity is reduced to O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't give you a full solution, but will try to guide you.

You should get a pencil and a paper, and ask yourself:

How many times does the statement `print asd[i], asd[j]` execute? (in worst case, meaning that you shouldn't really care about the condition there)
You'll find that it really depends on the loop above it, which gets executed `len(asd)` (denote it by `n`) times.

The only thing you need to know, how many times is the inner loop executed giving that the outer loop has `n` iterations? (`i` runs from 0 up to `n`)

If you still not sure about the result, just take a *real* example, say `n=20`, and calculate how many times is the lowest statement executed, this will give you a very good indication about the answer.

Comment: You are missing how many times each call is made for list lookups, adding and comparing.

Comment: @f.rodrigues no, this is big-O notation. Constants are explicitly omitted.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_zero(asd):
    for i in range(len(asd)):       # len called once =  o(1), range called once = o(1)
        for j in range(i,len(asd)): # len called once per i times = O(n), range called once per i times = O(n)
            if asd[i]+asd[j]==0:    # asd[i] called twice per j =  o(2*n²) 
                                    # adding is called once per j =  O(n²)
                                    # comparing with 0 is called once per j = O(n²)
                                        
                print asd[i],asd[j] # asd[i] is called twice per j = O(2*n²)
                
sum_zero(asd) # called once, o(1)
```

Assuming the worst case scenario (the `if-condition` always being true):

```
Total:
O(1) * 3
O(n) * 2
O(n²) * 6

O(6n² + 2n + 3)
```

A simple program to demonstrate the complexity:

```
target= []
quadraditc = []
linear = []
for x in xrange(1,100):
    linear.append(x)
    target.append(6*(x**2) + 2*x + 3)
    quadraditc.append(x**2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(linear,label="Linear")
plt.plot(target,label="Target Function")
plt.plot(quadraditc,label="Quadratic")
plt.ylabel('Complexity')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Program Complexity]

### EDIT:

As pointed out by @Micah Smith, the above answer is the *worst case operations*, **the Big-O is actually O(n^2)**, since the constants and lower order terms are omitted.

Comment: The worst case complexity is `6n^2 + 2n + 3` *operations* which means `O(n^2)`. Constants and lower order terms are omitted.

Comment: So, I don't mean to be pedantic, but this graph is extremely deceptive and doesn't actually reflect any understanding of big-O complexity, which explicitly only considers the largest term. In terms of complexity, the red and green lines should overlap.

Comment: As said before, reasoning is good and well-explained but you're missing the last step - which is removing constants, factors and lower order terms - `big O` of `6n^2 + 2n + 3` is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I added a disclaimer to this. Didn't know about ommiting terms and constants.

Comment: @f.rodrigues yep, `big O` only talks about `O`rders of magnitude